# How do I get a proportion of each row?

Tags: r

I have a large dataset over 10 000 records.
The data looks like this

```
Id  Ap   Ak    Al   Aj
602 1    0     1    1
603 0    1     1    1
603 1    1     1    0
```

Some of the Ids appear more than once. How do I to get the proportion for each row?
I have tried : `prop.table(table(rep$id), margin = 1)* 100`, this just returns 1s under each id.

Comment: Can you show the expected output  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  add_count(Id) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n / nrow(.), 
         .keep = "unused")
```

**Output**

```
   Id Ap Ak Al Aj      prop
1 602  1  0  1  1 0.3333333
2 603  0  1  1  1 0.6666667
3 603  1  1  1  0 0.6666667
```

Answer (score 2):

If we want the 'proportions'  for 'Id', extend the `proportions` to match the `names` with the column value of 'Id' after converting to `character`

```
df1$proportion <- 100 * proportions(table(df1$Id))[as.character(df1$Id)]
```

-output

```
> df1
   Id Ap Ak Al Aj proportion
1 602  1  0  1  1   33.33333
2 603  0  1  1  1   66.66667
3 603  1  1  1  0   66.66667
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Id = c(602L, 603L, 603L), Ap = c(1L, 0L, 1L), 
    Ak = c(0L, 1L, 1L), Al = c(1L, 1L, 1L), Aj = c(1L, 1L, 0L
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```